# In Antlr4 how to determine which lexer subtokens matched?

Tags: antlr4

Suppose I have this grammar for parsing ip addresses where each octet could be in decimal or in hex (this is a fictitious example to illustrate the essence of my real-world need):

```
grammar Ips;
ips:         ip (WS ip)*;
ip:          FOUR_OCTETS;
FOUR_OCTETS: OCTET '.' OCTET '.' OCTET '.' OCTET;
OCTET:       HEX_OCTET | DEC_OCTET;
HEX_OCTET:   'x[A-Fa-f][A-Fa-f]?;
DEC_OCTET:   [0-2][0-9]?[0-9]?;
WS:          [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

Using a base listener to walk the tree, when parser rule "ip" matches, is there a way to determine the composition of the FOUR_OCTETS lexer token? Ie, I want to know for each OCTET whether it was a HEX_OCTET or a DEC_OCTET.

In the parser rule's context object I see a way to get the FOUR_OCTETS token, but not any way to drill further into that token.

I realize that I could simply express the lexer tokens as parser rules instead, but then I have to deal with whitespacing explicitly and other messy aspects in my real-world use case.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like subtokens in ANTLR4. The lexer scans the input as defined by the lexer grammar and presents the final result only (with start and stop index, type, channel and a few other things). This final result is a single token, not a parse context as generated for parser rules (so there are no child tokens or similar).

If you can accept whitespaces around dots, you could define the ip rule so:

```
ip: OCTET DOT OCTET DOT OCTET DOT OCTET;
```

which would allow to inspect the individual octets. Otherwise you can only take the resulting string, split it by dots and process the 4 substrings manually.